# How to set Variable to echo 2 possible outcomes based on MYSQL row values

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get a variable to echo out Active or Not Active based upon a mysql row. In the database 0 represents not active and 1 represents active. When I send the report , I only get 0's and 1's. I am looking for help in how to set the values to echo out Active or Unactive in my report.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $status = $row["is_active"];

     if ($status == 1) {
        echo "Active";
    }
    if ($status == 0) {
        echo "Unactive";
    }
$message .= "<tr><td>".$row["course"]."</td><td>".$row["end_dt"]."</td><td>".$dpd."</td><td>".$status."</td><td>".$row["contact_name"]."</td><td>".$row["contact_phone"]."</td><td>".$row["contact_email"]."</td></tr>";
```

Comment: man, it's in the title. "set variable".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only get a `0` or `1` because you haven't changed the value of `$status`.  Instead of `echo`ing the result, you need store the value in a variable:

```
if ($status == 1) {
    $status_txt = "Active";
} else {
    $status_txt = "Unactive";
}

// Use $status_txt instead of $status in $message
```

I wouldn't recommend clobbering the value of `$status` in case you need it later.  For that reason, the text form is stored in `$status_txt`.

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly and I learned something along the way!